# Max current for 5ns pulsed CW laser diode?

Tags: laser-diode

I'm looking to reduce the cost of a lidar system by replacing the DPSS laser with a blue pulsed laser diode (this is for an underwater project)

Is there a rule of thumb for the appropriate current to use to generate nanosecond pulses from a CW diode?

Particularly I am thinking of 1.6W 450nm diode being driven at 20kHz (so 0.01% duty cycle?)

Also, is what I am investigating at all practical?!

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "Is there a rule of thumb for the appropriate current to use to generate nanosecond pulses from a CW diode?". You want to drive the laser with nanosecond current pulses that are large enough to give whatever power output you need.

Comment: My understanding is that if I pulse a CW diode I can use a larger current than in CW mode as there is less of a heat problem.  I thought it might be possible to drive diodes at higher pulse currents than are possible as a CW.  That still doesn't sound very clear when I reread it sorry!

Comment: Read the laser data sheet.

Comment: Oh right, well yes as long as you don't exceed the overall power rating of the diode you can do that. Do you have the datasheet of the LD you want to use?

Comment: Here’s the datasheet of the osram diode I was thinking about.  Unfortunately it has been discontinued this morning!!https://www.lasercomponents.com/fileadmin/user_upload/home/Datasheets/osram/pl_tb450b.pdf